# EGit - Project subfolder in repository

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

I have the following problem with EGit 3.4.2.201412180340-r in Eclipse Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1), using GitHub (which should be mostly irrelevant):

I have a example java project set up that is configured with EGit and is connected to a GitHub Repository. I commited a few example changes to `master` and pushed them as well.

The problem is: My repositories always have a weird kind of file layout:
`Repository Root >`**`MyProjectName`**`> src > cf > randers > myproject > main > Main.java`

The most projects I know on GitHub have the following layout:
`Repository Root > src > cf > randers > myproject > main > Main.java`

Can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clone your GitHub repo (in command-line, outside Eclipse), and:

- `git mv` everything under `MyProjectName` in the root folder of that repo
- `git add`, `git commit` and `git push` that move.
- import that `.eclipse` (now move under the root of the local git repo) in a new Eclipse workspace.