# import repository from github to eclipse get an empty project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github, import

I try to import GitHub projetc to my eclipse workspace using import- git Repository-> clone URI-> I introduce URI -> import using New project Wizard.

Repository is : https://github.com/lyesqc/myjpa

How can I get the full project in my Eclipse? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach:

- clone the repo locally first (outside Eclipse, with git clone)
- Then [import the Maven project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36242422/6309), with  `File > Import` (Type `Maven` in the search box under `Select an import source`), and `Select Existing Maven Projects`.

Comment: Thank you, using this way it work, have you an idea whay doesn't work using the first way?

Comment: using the second approah, when i push, a subdirectory with a name of my eclipse project is created in github repository containing my project, but i like to push directly into git repository without adding subdodirectory, thank you

Comment: @Lyes Try https://stackoverflow.com/q/14107367/6309 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/28658456/6309: An eclipse project should be at the root of a Git repo.